# Shell script capturing values from output of command

Tags: bash, scripting, shell, regex

From a shell script, I run a ping command:

```
ping -c4 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=34.2 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=58 time=30.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=58 time=29.6 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=58 time=29.3 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3006ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 29.311/31.022/34.242/1.951 ms
```

I need to capture the packet loss ( the 0% in the example above) into a variable in the shell script for further processing. Can somebody please point me in the right direction on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use grep and awk to capture the packet loss from the output of the ping command. Here's an example:

```
ping_result=$(ping -c4 8.8.8.8)
packet_loss=$(echo "$ping_result" | grep -oP '\d+% packet loss')
echo "Packet Loss: $packet_loss"
```

In this example, you store the result on a variable called ping_result, for further processing.

In the packet_loss line, you use grep with Perl parameters to extract the desired information (% packet loss).

Finally, you output the variable in the last line.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Something like in `awk` can do the work:

```
packet_lost=$(ping -c4 8.8.8.8|awk '/packet loss/ {print $6}')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you *only* want to know if *all* the packets were lost (i.e. host is unreachable), some versions of `ping` [return an exit code of 1](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/ping-error-exit-codes-4175724938/#:%7E:text=If%20ping%20does%20not%20receive,it%20exits%20with%20code%200.) in such cases: